# NSComboBox autocompletion with an NSValueTransformer

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nscombobox

I want to make an `NSComboBox` with a list of predetermined values. The underlying objects are a custom Swift struct, and I'm using a custom `NSValueTransformer` to transform those to and from the underlying string representation I'm storing.

I want to limit the user to the options in the popup, but still allow autocompletion. I'm using a data source for it, and I'm using Cocoa bindings to a Core Data object, and tried using the KVO Core Data validation, like I'm using in a regular (non-combo) text field, but that field doesn't have a value transformer.

The first problem is that if I set the behavior to `Selectable`, the transformation happens correctly and the right value is saved, and the transformed values get passed to the KVO validation. But then the user can't type and get autocompletion. If I set `Editable`, then you're able to type and autocomplete, but no value gets transformed, validated, or saved.

I want the KVO validation in place, so that I can prevent the user from entering arbitrary values - I want autocompletion, but not freeform entry.

These are my Attributes and Bindings inspectors for the combo box:

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you don't want the user to enter arbitrary values, is there a particular reason you are wanting to use a combo box?

Comment: @red_menace You know, I was using `NSComboBox` for something else in the same window and totally forgot about NSPopupButton. If you'd want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **NSComboBox** is designed to allow the user to input custom values in addition to a list of menu items, so it includes a text field.  If you don’t want this behavior, an **NSPopUpButton** can be used, which just has a list of items.  A pop-up button doesn’t have autocompletion per se, but like other menus, items can be selected by typing the name.